# What is the best way to have only single database connection throughout whole android app life?

Tags: php, android, mysql, database-connection

I am quite new to android, and I have some newbie question for you all. I have an interactive app, and on one of the Activities I have "auto fill", where on every text change I load some JSON from the DB (PHP and MYSQL connection) and show it in a listview. Now, in order to make it faster, I guess i need a single connection when the user opens the app and have it open until he closes, because intuitively if I connect and disconnect to the database every time he enters a character, it makes it slow, even in localhost. I thought of using singleton, but I've read around that using static is not the best bet, and there are other ways (not explained unfortunately). So..what should I do? Should I also include the buffers and streams in my single connection point? Any help is appreciated. Here is some of my connection code..

```
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) qurl.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
```

Comment: @Razgriz I really thought my question is valid..

Comment: wondering why you tagged as php and mysql with no code to support the question.

Comment: btw, you have a lot of questions that aren't marked as solved and are still considered "open". have any of those get solved at all? if so, you could mark them as being solved with a simple tick next to them

Comment: Well, the question is not really about the code. I posted this just as an example what I want to simplify (make a single connection of)

Comment: Well, we really prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.

Comment: @Razgriz I apologize then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere is no way, not how you're doing it.  You're making individual HTTP connections for each request.  Unless your webserver only maintains a single instance of a database connection for all requests, its going to create new ones for each request (this would also mean your website only has a single server-  in other words not true for any non-trivial app).

My suggestion is to redesign your feature such that you aren't making an HTTP request per character.  That means either removing autofill, or sending down more data with each request and doing processing client side to filter out possibilities.  Or accepting that autofill responses will be slow and may be obsolete by the time they return.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. This is an answer I was looking for. If this is the case, I will make it so it starts working after 2,3 characters. That will improve it a little i guess.